# GridView in android, gridView.setAdapater(this) error

Tags: java, android, gridview

I follow some tutorial "How to use GridView in android" and try to make Gallery....
but why? 
I already did same with tutorial did....

this file GridActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));  

}
```

and this for file ImageAdapter.java :

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapater(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    public long getItemId (int position) {
        return 0;   
    }

    public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView  imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70,70));
        return imageView;           
    }       

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.image1
    };

}
```

there's no error...
but when I tried to run with emulator...

"Unfotunetly, ........... has stop"

please....help...me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new ImageAdapter(this)` Needs a constructor that takes context as the param.

Change this

```
 public void ImageAdapater(Context c) { //remove void for constructor
```

to

```
 public ImageAdapater(Context c) {
```

More info

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: @user2467583 post a new question and post the logcat the stacktrace has details regarding the crash the exception that causes the crash. Posting that will help resolve your new problem